Syntax error while finding total of column within gallery in Power App
I have a gallery control in power app with months column from Jan to Dec. Each column will have input text control of Number type. The controls are editable. I have added a row before header with Label control in scrollable container to show the total of each column from Jan to Dec. I want it to get displayed on the run as user edit any Input text of any column, it should display SUM() of each column in above Label.
The logic that I have used is having some syntax error. Unable to find error:
Text(
   Sum(
      ForAll(
            Gallery1_1.AllItems, Value(TextInputJan_1.Text)
      )
   )
)

The error I am getting under ForAll condition is Expected number. We expect a number at this point in the formula.

The Sum function has two "overloads": you can either pass to it a list of numbers, to get their sum:
Sum(1, 2, 3, 4) // Will return 10

Or you can pass a table to it, and an expression to be evaluated for every item of the table:
Sum([{a:1}, {a:3}, {a:5}], a) // Will return 9

In your scenario, the argument to the Sum function is the result of the ForAll function, which is a table; this is not a supported way to call that function today.
To solve that, you can remove the ForAll call: Gallery1_1.AllItems is a table where one of its properties is TextInputJan_1, so you can use it directly:
Text(
    Sum(
        Gallery1.AllItems,
        Value(TextInputJan_1.Text)
    )
)

